# Refactoring: returning a promise from a value or an existing promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

## My scenario

I used to have some `node.js` implementation done using `callbacks` but I am now refactoring my code to use `Promises` instead - using `Q` module. I have the following `update()` function where the inner `_update()` function already returns a `Promise`:

```
exports.update = function(id, template, callback) {
  if (!_isValid(template)){
    return callback(new Error('Invalid data', Error.INVALID_DATA));
  }

  _update(id, template) // this already returns a promise
  .then(function() {
    console.log('UPDATE was OK!');
    callback();
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('UPDATE with ERRORs!');
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

### My question

I would like to achieve *something like the following*:

```
exports.update = function(id, template) {
  if (!_isValid(template)){
    // how could I make it return a valid Promise Error?
    return reject(new Error('Invalid data', Error.INVALID_DATA));
  }

  return _update(id, template) // return the promise
  .done();
};
```

Because `_update()` already returns a `promise`, I guess changing it this way would be enough (wouldn't be?):

```
  return _update(id, template)
  .done();
```

And... what about if the `condition` inside the `if-clause` equals `true`? How could I refactor

`return callback(new Error('Invalid data', BaboonError.INVALID_DATA));`

to throw an `error` to avoid passing the `callback` into `update()` and handling that error (or what ever error could ever be returning `_update()`)?

Also, calling `update()`:

```
myModule.update(someId, someTemplate)
.then(function() { /* if the promise returned ok, let's do something */ })
.catch(function(err) { /* wish to handle errors here if there was any */});
```

somewhere else in my code:

- if there is an error during the `promise` propagation - it should handle it,
- or, if there wasn't an error - it should do some other things

Am I close to what I am expecting? How could I finally achieve it?

Comment: returning `???.done()` does **not** return a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, got it! Returning it is enough. `done()` just for terminating chains. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see only two problems.

1. If you want to explicitly return a rejected promise with a value, you should do that with [`Q.reject`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qrejectreason).
2. Calling [`.done()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress) on promise means that the promise ends there. It cannot be chained further.

So, your code would look like this

```
exports.update = function (id, template) {
  if (!_isValid(template)) {
    return Q.reject(new Error('Invalid data', Error.INVALID_DATA));
  }

  return _update(id, template);
};
```

Now, the `update` function just returns a promise always. Its up to the callers to attach the success or failure handlers to it.

Comment: Yes, the callers should do that - in this case it is going to be me so I wanted to make sure it could be done!
By the way, to make things clearer: we'd use `Q.reject` here because `_update()` already returns a _Promise_ and for that reason using `deferred`s or `new Q.Promise`s would be using some **Promise antipatterns**, right?